# How to create Previous/Next buttons above keyboard like in Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to add Previous/Next buttons above the keyboard like in mobile Safari. There are a lot of questions about that here on StackOverflow, but most answers are to use inputAccessoryView.
I tried that and it looks like this:

[image: My app]

Is there anyway to have the buttons in the toolbar bellow, like it works in mobile Safari??

This is how it looks like in Safari:

[image: Mobile Safari]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  What do you mean by "have the buttons in the toolbar below"?

Comment: https://github.com/simonbs/BSKeyboardControls

Comment: @Jim: I have edited my question with a screenshot from Safari

Comment: @jose920405: Thanks, but unless I'm missing something, BSKeyboardControls works the same way. Here is a screenshot from their example app: http://i.imgur.com/Jh0EGlS.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what I was looking for is [inputAssistantItem](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder/1621135-inputassistantitem).

It allows you to add and change buttons in the keyboard's shortcut bar.

```
UIBarButtonItem* nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithImage:nextImage
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(nextField:)];
UIBarButtonItem* previousButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithImage:previousImage
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(previousField:)];
NSArray *buttonGroups = @[[[UIBarButtonItemGroup alloc]
                           initWithBarButtonItems:@[previousButton, nextButton]
                           representativeItem:nil]];

textField.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = buttonGroups;
```

Comment: The shortcuts bar is not available on iPhone or iPod Touch.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *previous = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:103  target:self action:@selector(previousButtonTapped:)];
UIBarButtonItem *fixedSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[fixedSpace setWidth:6.0];
UIBarButtonItem *next = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:104 target:self action:@selector(nextButtonTapped:)];
```

[image: toolbar with previous/next bar button items]